# Using open(), read() and write() system calls to copy a file

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm having trouble using `read()`, `write()`, and `open()` to copy a file into a new directory. I'm able to create a new file with `open()` and I'm able to write to the terminal with `write()` but I was under the assumption that if I passed my `int` file descriptor from open to write, write would write to the specified file.

In addition to this, once I open a file the permissions are all funky and I can only open it as root. Each time I create a file, it's completely empty but I can see the entire file I just read be printed out in the terminal.

I've read through the man files for each system call but I'm still not grasping what the issue is here.

Here's my code:

```
void *scanFile( s_request *request )
{
    //TODO Print out all struct variables.
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    int readFileReference;
    int writeFileReference;
    int bufferSize = request->bufferSize;
    int numberOfBytesRead = bufferSize;
    int *buffer[bufferSize];

    if ((readFileReference = open(request->file, O_RDONLY)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Failed to open file. Aborting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((writeFileReference = open("newfile.txt", O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR) == -1))
    {
        printf("Failed to open write file. Aborting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((read(readFileReference, buffer, numberOfBytesRead)) != 0)
    {
        write(writeFileReference, buffer, bufferSize);
        bzero(buffer, bufferSize);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Fixed the issue:

Updated code:

```
void *scanFile( s_request *request )
{
    //TODO Print out all struct variables.
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    int readFileReference;
    int writeFileReference;
    int bufferSize = request->bufferSize;
    int numberOfBytesRead = bufferSize;
    int *buffer[bufferSize];

    if ((readFileReference = open(request->file, O_RDONLY)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Failed to open file. Aborting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((writeFileReference = open("newfile.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0777)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Failed to open write file. Aborting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((read(readFileReference, buffer, numberOfBytesRead)) != 0)
    {
        write(writeFileReference, buffer, bufferSize);
        bzero(buffer, bufferSize);
    }

    close(writeFileReference);
    close(readFileReference);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Comment: You failed to read the documentation for `open`. It takes *three* arguments when creating a file.

Comment: You right. Thanks @ZanLynx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ((writeFileReference = open("newfile.txt", O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR) == -1))
```

You've got the parentheses wrong on this line. (It's correct on the `readFileReference` line.) What you want is:

```
if ((writeFileReference = open("newfile.txt", O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR)) == -1)
                                                                         ^^^    ^^^
```

Your original version of that line was calling `open()`, performing a comparison to `-1`, then assigning **the result of that comparison** to `writeFileReference`.

Additionally:

- As noted by Zan Lynx in a comment, you need to pass a permissions value to `open()` when creating a file. `0666` is typically correct -- it'll create the file as readable/writable. (It's modified by the process umask, so it'll end up creating the file as `0644` under a typical configuration.)
- You need to save the return value from `read` somewhere and pass that as the third argument to `write` (instead of `bufferSize`). Otherwise, your program will write more bytes than were read, e.g. when copying small files.
- Technically, you should be checking the return value from `write()`. Just like `read()`, it's not guaranteed to complete a full write every time it's called. (In practice, when working with regular files, it will always either complete the write or return an error, but there are some esoteric situations where this may not be the case.)
- You don't need to `bzero()` the buffer after writing from it.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! And I managed to solve it while adding more code.